# Add static block to home page

Tags: static-block

I have looked and tried methods in other topics but I cannot find anything that will work.

I want to keep my **homepage organized** and I would like to add "sections" like **about us** and **contact** section to the **home page**.

I tried adding the the code like

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-7">
   {{block type="cms/block" block_id="about_us"}}
 </div>
</div>
```

But isnt showing the content fromt he block. I tried doing it with a widget and it did show but it was stuck in the container and the bg image was not going full width.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to add below code in CMS Page with you block id

```
{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="18"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('about_us'); ?>
```

For getting static Block from a `.phtml` file `{{block type="cms/block" block_id="about_us"}}` is used to get static block in magento ver 1.9.2.4 or before.